# Update custom mediator jar files without restarting wso2ei (integrator) server

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

Is there a way to update/upgrade a custom mediator (jar file) located in `wso2ei/lib` folder without having to restart the whole wso2ei server (`integrator.sh`)?

There is a Carbnon Application that uses lets say x mediator (`x.jar`), and whenever there is an updated version of the mediator (`x.jar`), what I do atm is:

- stop wso2 integrator `integrator.sh -stop`
- delete all `dropins/*`
- delete all `tmp/*`
- delete `x.jar` in `wso2ei/lib`
- upload the new `x.jar` in that directory
- start wso2 integrator `integrator.sh -start`

Answer (score 1):

By default - it is not supported to replace the library on the fly (except web applications). So officially if you need to to keep your services up and running, you should use multiple EI nodes and use rolling update. I suggest you to keep it simple.

However - if you are feeling like going deeper - the carbon wso2 code (base of the wso2ei) is built on an p2 osgi container that would in theory allow you to install and uninstall bundles on the fly. (though wso2 will probably not support this type of deployment)

- You can start the wso2ei with `-DosgiConsole`parameter and you can run the osgi console on a specific port `-DosgiConsole=<port number>`, see https://www.yenlo.com/blog/access-wso2-osgi-console-using-telnet
- Here we assume you can create an osgi bundle, not a simple jar library (you should be really familiar with osgi technology and options)
- From the console you may install, uninstall bundles  https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Console_Users_Guide and there are `install` and `uninstall`command

Note well - if there are any other bundles which are using your classes, they become stopped and installing different version may not cause them recover (e.g. you cannot just replace already loaded .db driver)